# Gluon Mobile application installed successfully but crashes when i open it in android

Tags: java, android, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon-mobile

I am creating a mobile android app using JavaFX, scene builder and Gluon Mobile framework.

i have my android connected to it a Samsung s10e 
and i am seeing that the app is successfully installing to the device, but when i go to run it it crashes on the phone 
I gave my logs to a android developer and he stated this is the issue:

Looks like that this is the part that it doesn't like, it can't find this static method getLogger.:

```
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.gluonapplication, PID: 14678
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; in class Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; or its super classes (declaration of 'sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
```

He is not familiar with javafx or gluon mobile, so he couldn't help

please help me...

these are the logs:

```
--------- beginning of crash
04-28 04:29:04.701  1059 19010 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 19010 (NuPlayerRendere), pid 1059 (mediaserver)
04-28 04:29:04.815 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-28 04:29:04.815 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/beyond0qltesq/beyond0q:10/QP1A.190711.020/G970USQS3CTB6:user/release-keys'
04-28 04:29:04.815 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : Revision: '17'
04-28 04:29:04.815 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2020-04-28 04:29:04-0500
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : pid: 1059, tid: 19010, name: NuPlayerRendere  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : uid: 1013
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/nuplayer/NuPlayerRenderer.cpp:1846 CHECK(entry->mBuffer->meta()->findInt64("timeUs", &mediaTimeUs)) failed.'
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  00004a42  r2  00000006  r3  e4cabb68
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :     r4  e4cabb7c  r5  e4cabb60  r6  00000423  r7  0000016b
04-28 04:29:04.816 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :     r8  e4cabb78  r9  e4cabb68  r10 e4cabb98  r11 e4cabb88
04-28 04:29:04.817 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :     ip  00004a42  sp  e4cabb38  lr  eca3d63f  pc  eca3d652
04-28 04:29:04.846 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : 
04-28 04:29:04.846 19017 19017 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
04-28 04:29:04.846 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 00061652  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166) (BuildId: dd992ae746dab7bd779edc87ba383c6e)
04-28 04:29:04.846 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00005a95  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+176) (BuildId: 51381cf619d06e2c3a43605a202500ea)
04-28 04:29:04.846 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 00099c6d  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (android::NuPlayer::Renderer::onDrainAudioQueue()+2196) (BuildId: 682555ea0f45b6ac9f1a8b617477c11e)
04-28 04:29:04.847 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00097797  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (android::NuPlayer::Renderer::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+2030) (BuildId: 682555ea0f45b6ac9f1a8b617477c11e)
04-28 04:29:04.847 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00012fdd  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHandler::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+24) (BuildId: 56e4e32b3c0fa3476b6b9885c4e9b8fb)
04-28 04:29:04.847 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00015571  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AMessage::deliver()+60) (BuildId: 56e4e32b3c0fa3476b6b9885c4e9b8fb)
04-28 04:29:04.847 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00013713  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+434) (BuildId: 56e4e32b3c0fa3476b6b9885c4e9b8fb)
04-28 04:29:04.847 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0000d935  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+152) (BuildId: 99cbb579e9ea71e122fb09aa66ab824b)
04-28 04:29:04.847 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 000ac7dd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20) (BuildId: dd992ae746dab7bd779edc87ba383c6e)
04-28 04:29:04.847 19017 19017 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 00062d89  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: dd992ae746dab7bd779edc87ba383c6e)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.gluonapplication, PID: 14678
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; in class Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; or its super classes (declaration of 'sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.util.Logging.getCSSLogger(Logging.java:98)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser.<clinit>(CSSParser.java:164)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.loadStylesheetUnPrivileged(StyleManager.java:1079)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.loadStylesheet(StyleManager.java:910)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager._addUserAgentStylesheet(StyleManager.java:1263)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.setUserAgentStylesheets(StyleManager.java:1204)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$_setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet$14(PlatformImpl.java:698)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$13(Unknown Source:2)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$14.run(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl._setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:697)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet$11(PlatformImpl.java:550)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$10(Unknown Source:2)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$11.run(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(Unknown Source:2)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:59)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source:7)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
04-28 22:14:00.513 14678 22812 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.gluonapplication, PID: 22897
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; in class Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; or its super classes (declaration of 'sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.util.Logging.getCSSLogger(Logging.java:98)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser.<clinit>(CSSParser.java:164)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.loadStylesheetUnPrivileged(StyleManager.java:1079)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.loadStylesheet(StyleManager.java:910)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager._addUserAgentStylesheet(StyleManager.java:1263)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.setUserAgentStylesheets(StyleManager.java:1204)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$_setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet$14(PlatformImpl.java:698)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$13(Unknown Source:2)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$14.run(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl._setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:697)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet$11(PlatformImpl.java:550)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$10(Unknown Source:2)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$11.run(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(Unknown Source:2)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:59)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(Unknown Source:4)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source:7)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
04-28 22:14:02.345 22897 22933 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
04-28 22:17:46.660 26651 26687 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
04-28 22:17:46.660 26651 26687 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.gluonapplication, PID: 26651
04-28 22:17:46.660 26651 26687 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; in class Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; or its super classes (declaration of 'sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
04-28 22:17:46.660 26651 26687 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.util.Logging.getCSSLogger(Logging.java:98)
```

Comment: That log is not relevant to find out the reason of the crash. You need to run `adb logcat` for that.

Comment: I was able to add the logcat of all the errors through android device monitor

Comment: Are you sure that is the full stacktrace? It would be good if you get the full logcat for the process (and share a link to it).

Comment: I have added the full tracer please help

Comment: What is your JDK version? You should be using Java 1.8, but what version number?

Comment: I am using 1.8.